# Magento Edit profile AJAX

Tags: ajax, magento

I'm looking for your help. I want change an avatar picture with Ajax in Magento.
My form work without AJAX, it's the default form `action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/editProfile') ?>"`

This is my code :

```
     <form id="avatarform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
         <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>                    
            <input type="file" name="avatar"/>
            <a><button type="submit" class="general-btn"><span><?php echo $this->__('Save Profile') ?></span></button></a>  
     </form>
```

And my JS function for now :

```
jQuery("#avatarform").submit(function(){
            //alert ("test");   
            //jQuery.post('<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/editProfile') ?>');       
            //return false;

            url = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/editProfile') ?>';             
            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                parameters: {isAjax: 1, method: 'POST'},
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                }
            }); 
        });
```

Do you have a suggestion for me ?

Thanks in advance.

Edit : With this new code, I can get the sucess alert.

```
jQuery('#avatar').live('change', function() {   
            //alert('test');
            var boxval = jQuery("#avatar").val();
            var dataString = 'avatar='+ boxval;
            //document.avatarform3.submit();        
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                url: "http://localhost/magento-sample/index.php/customer/account/editProfile",
                success: function(html) {
                alert('sucess');                                        
                }
            });
        });
```

But the form is not submit. Maybe I miss to add the correct data/parametrs, but Why I need to add some param in Ajax when it works with the normal request mode ? And how can I found the right param to add ?

Thx.

Comment: what issues have you encountered? what it the actual question here?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. It's simple, my JS function doesn't submit my form and I don't know why.

Comment: Does it not submit the form correctly because you are actually submitting nothing in the `parameters` which includes information from your form? There's some great Prototype AJAX tutorials out there: http://24ways.org/2005/easy-ajax-with-prototype

Comment: I read it, but I don't find the fix.

Answer (score 0):

How are you reading your parameters on form submission, you need to read request parameter when post method is used.